# Regex + sign followed by numbers

Tags: java, regex, expression

Hi i want to find Strings like "+19" in Java

so a + sign followed by infinite amount of numbers.

How do i do this?

Tried "+[0123456789]"
and "\+[0123456789]"

thank you :)

Comment: Use double backslashes before the plus symbol. `"\\+[0-9]"`

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex you want to use:

```
\\+\\d+
```

Two kinds of plus are being used here.  The first is escaped with two backslashes because it is treated as a literal.  The second one means match 1 of more times (i.e. match any digit one or more times).

**Code:**

```
String input = "+19";
if (input.matches("\\+\\d+")) {
    System.out.println("input string matches");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir !!! :) :) :)  It works nicely !! But why would "\\+\d" be incorrect? :) what is the extra "\" for ? :)

Comment: You need to pass `\d` to the regex engine.  If you used `\d` literally, you would just be passing the letter `d` to the engine.

Comment: A okay so every part of the expression needs an aditional "\" because of the java String handling ?! And this is where i got confused :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to match a plus you need to escape it with two backslashes in a C string literal that Java uses. A literal plus needs to be either escaped or put into a character class, `[+]`. If you just use a plus symbol, it becomes a quantifier that matches the previous symbol or group one or more number of times.

Also, note that the `\d` shorthand digit class can match more than just ASCII digits if `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag is passed  to `Pattern.compile` (or embedded `(?U)` flag is added at the start of the pattern). It is advised to use unambiguous patterns in case the code might be maintained or enhanced/adjusted by different developers later.

Most people prefer patterns without escaping backslashes if possible since that allows to avoid issues like the one you faced.

Here is a version of the regex that does not require any escaping:

```
"[+][0-9]+"
```

Also, the plus quantifier does not match an infinite number of digits, only MAX_UINT number of times.

Comment: Any feedback? Let me know if anything is still unclear.